# my text is not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css

I have two `<ul>` and Im having a problem with my second `<ul>`, that is the `<ul>` with more content.

In this second `<ul>` my last line appears floated at left and dont appears below my penultimate line.

**Like this:**

[image]

Somebody there knows how I can align this correctly?

**My jsfiddle** with the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/8UQeF/2/

**My html:**

```
 <div id="example">
                    <img src="images/image1.jpg" width="180" height="170" />
                    <h2>1º ul</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Here I have two list items:</li>
                        <li><strong>List item 1:</strong> content of list item 1</li>
                        <li><strong>List Item 2</strong>content of list item 2</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="clear"></div>
                     <img  src="images/image2.jpg" width="180" height="170" />
                    <h2>2º ul</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Here I have four list items:</li>
                        <li><strong>List item 1</strong> content of list item 1</li>
                        <li><strong>Penultimate line</strong> This is my penultimate line and works fine but next line wont work fine because exceeds the height of image I guess, but my image needs to have this height</li>
                        <li><strong>This is a litem item with more content then the others and its not working fine </strong> because my last line is not below the penultimate line, somebody there knows how I can solve this situation?</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

**My html:**

```
   <div id="example">
                <img src="images/image1.jpg" width="180" height="170" />
                <h2>1º ul</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>Here I have two list items:</li>
                    <li><strong>List item 1:</strong> content of list item 1</li>
                    <li><strong>List Item 2</strong>content of list item 2</li>
                </ul>
                <div id="clear"></div>
                 <img  src="images/image2.jpg" width="180" height="170" />
                <h2>2º ul</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>Here I have four list items:</li>
                    <li><strong>List item 1</strong> content of list item 1</li>
                    <li><strong>Penultimate line</strong> This is my penultimate line and works fine but next line wont work fine because exceeds the height of image I guess, but my image needs to have this height</li>
                    <li><strong>This is a litem item with more content then the others and its not working fine </strong> because my last line is not below the penultimate line, somebody there knows how I can solve this situation?</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**My css:**

```
#example {width:700px; height:auto;  font-size:16px; margin:15px 0 0 0; }
#example img{float:left; margin-right:10px; }
#example h2{color:#444; font-size:18px; }
#example p{ text-align:justify; font-size:16px; margin-top:10px; }
#clear{clear:both; margin-top:30px;}
#example ul {list-style:none;}
#example  ul li {margin-top:5px;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
#example ul {list-style:none;float:left;margin:0;padding:0;width:60%}
```

With this solution you can add all text that you want.

Answer (score 3):

You're after hanging indents, but that's not how elements surrounding floats work.

They technically are all starting at the same `left` point, however they are being pushed to the right of the floated image. Once the floated image ends, there's nothing stopping the inline text from starting where it's supposed to: at the leftmost point of the block-level container.

You need to set up a box to push the elements away from the floated image:

http://jsfiddle.net/8UQeF/4/

```
#example .hanging-indent { margin-left: 190px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if i got the question right, but here goes.

Just add some padding to the bottom of the image.

```
 <img  src="images/image2.jpg" width="180" height="170" style="padding-bottom:40px;" />
```

(yeah, maybe not inline, but you get the ideea)

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8UQeF/3/

Again, sorry if i misunderstood your question

Comment: Thank you very much, it also works like Ragnar answer!

Answer (score 0):

What about this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8UQeF/8/)?

I simply added a

```
margin-bottom: -15px;
```

to the h2 element